# How to get field value in MERN stack?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, fetch, mern

I have test document to render page. I want to get value of field *title* by using fetch API.

[image]

I already have working server and I can get data from database.
[image]

But I have error when try to render page where want to get title.

```js
    const getTitle = async () =>{
        let result =  await fetch('http://localhost:5000/book/645774394671b0aa9042918d')
        .then(res => res.json())
        let title = result.title
        return title
    }

    return(
        <>
            <ProductDetials 
                title={getTitle()}
                format={'Текст'}
                author={'Джордж Оруэл'}
                recomendedAge={18}
                publisher={'АСТ'}
                rate={4.8}
                ratesCount={466}
                reviewCount={45}
                price={460}
                fakePrice={660}
                volume={280}
                genre={'Современные детективы'}
                dateWriting={2022}
            />
        </>
    )
```

I have error which say *Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]).*. But if I check type of function result I have *string* answer.

What I do wrong?

Comment: `getTitle` is async, should you be `await`ing it?

Comment: @Joe I cant await this. I get erro - *'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.*